Value Error: y contains previously unseen labels: [8 9]
I have a dataset, that I use label_encoding for data preprocessing before feed into the model.
I first label_encoding all of my data, then split the data into training and testing.
And I want to use "label_encoder.inverse_transform" to reverse the code, but it has this error message:
y contains previously unseen labels: [8 9]

The error message was clear, but that's the part that I am confused, because I label-encoded all of the data before splitting.
I've checked the other post: Getting ValueError: y contains new labels when using scikit learn's LabelEncoder, but that post was about the author had new dataset as testing data, mine on the otherhand, I did label_encoding the whole dataset and then split. So the encoder should have already seen all of my data, including x_test.
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
category =[]
data_encoded = data_cleaned
for i in data_cleaned.columns:
    if data_cleaned[i].dtype == 'category':
        category.append(i)
        data_encoded[i] = label_encoder.fit_transform(data_cleaned[i])

Split the training and testing data
target_variable = ['target']
data_encoded = data_encoded.dropna(subset=target_variable)
x = data_encoded.drop(target_variable, axis=1)
y = data_encoded[target_variable]

And try to reverse the encoded label
//only want to reverse the category column
for i in category:
    X_test[i] = label_encoder.inverse_transform(X_test[i])
    print(X_test[i])

If anyone could point some direction that would be great!

This question is similar to: Getting ValueError: y contains new labels when using scikit learn's LabelEncoder. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I've checked that post before submitting my question. The difference is that author of that post fed new data to testing, so it is possible that the encoder didn't see some of the data before. For my case, I first encoded the data, then split. In this case, my encoder should have seen all of the data. That's my understanding

The issue is that in your loop, the label_encoder keep getting fit_transform to a new column, in which it relearns the new encoding. So when you do inverse_transform, the label_encoder only has the information from the last column it encoded. You will need to create a LE for each column and can use it to inverse_transform for each column.
Here is what I would suggest you to do:
# List of Label Encoder for each categorical feature
le = [LabelEncoder() for i in range(len(category))]
data_encoded = data_cleaned
for i in range(len(category)): 
    feat = cat_feat[i]
    data_encoded[feat] = le[i].fit_transform(data_cleaned[feat])

# After splitting:
for i in range(len(category)): 
    feat = category[i]
    X_test[feat] = le[i].inverse_transform(X_test[feat])
    print(X_test[feat])


Thank you so much! I never think of that, I thought it would just create it self. I will defintely try this out!
